# cotangent space

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be a field and $L$ be its field extension, $K\subset L.$ Let $V \subset L^n$ and let $\mathcal{I}(V)\subset K[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$ be its vanishing ideal.  Let  $R=K[x_{1},..,x_{n}]/\mathcal{I}(V)$ and $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal in $R.$

Consider the local ring $R_{\mathfrak{m}},$ then I think  $$L=R_{\mathfrak{m}}/\mathfrak{m}.$$ Thus the cotantangent space $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ is an $L$-vector space.

i am kind of confused whether the residue field should be  $L$ or $K.$

Comment: You write $V \subset L^n$ and $\mathcal{I}(V) \subset K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ - are you contracting under the inclusion $K[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \subseteq L[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$? E.g. if $V = \{i\} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, what is $\mathcal{I}(V) \subseteq \mathbb{R}[x]$? Are you assuming $L/K$ is finite?

Comment: Dear @zcn: if $V=\{i\}$, then $\mathcal I(V)=(x^2+1)\subset \mathbb R[x]$. There is no reason to assume that $L/K$ is finite. The context is pre-Grothendieck algebraic geometry. This kind of presentation with two  fields, one for the equations and one for the solutions has the advantage of being more elementary than scheme theory and is adopted for example by Kunz in [his excellent book](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Introduction_to_Commutative_Algebra_and.html?id=3A2HmLLxa-QC&redir_esc=y) .

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: The question had somehow not made too much sense to me, so I was trying to clarify what the OP had in mind. I agree with the interpretation in your +1 answer though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The residue field is neither $K$ nor $L$ in general!

For example, take $K=\mathbb Q\subset L=\mathbb C, n=1, V=\{i,-i\}\subset \mathbb C^1$, so that $\mathcal I(V)=(X^2+1)\subset \mathbb Q[X]$ .
Then $R=\mathbb Q[X]/(X^2+1)=\mathbb Q(i)$ and necessarily $\mathfrak m=(0)\subset R$, so that the residue field $\kappa(\mathfrak m)=\mathbb Q(i)$ is different from both $K=\mathbb Q$ and $L=\mathbb C$ .

Comment: Thank You very much, for clearing my confusion.

Comment: You are welcome, dear user157648.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: One more point of clarification (if you don't mind): If $V = \{\pi\} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, what are you taking as $\mathcal{I}(V) \subset \mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Comment: @zcn: $\mathcal I(\{\pi\})=(0)\subset \mathbb Q[X]$. And I don't mind in the least answering your interesting question...